# Javascript json object how to move changed data to a new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have 2 json object.

the first one holds data from the client form.

```
{
       "name": "Example name",
       "company": {
         "name": "new company",
         "size": "FIVE",
         "licenseInfo": {
            "isActive": "0"
         }
       }
}
```

and in my other object, I know which fields are modified in this form. If value is true then it has changed. The plugin I use gives me this information.

```
{
       "name": true,
       "company": { 
         "size": true,
         "licenseInfo": {
            "isActive": true
         }
       }
}
```

I want to compare these 2 objects and get a submit object with only changed data as follows.
company name has not been changed and I do not want to submit company.name

```
{
       "name": "Example name",
       "company": { 
         "size": "FIVE",
         "licenseInfo": {
            "isActive": "0"
         }
       }
}
```

I can manually control the fields one by one, but I want to create a dynamic compare function so I can use it on my other forms.

Comment: Please be aware that none of the examples are valid JSON

Comment: I'm not applying blame. The examples are still not valid JSON. Property names must also be quoted

Comment: That's a good site to view JSON data, but it doesn't validate it. Use https://jsonlint.com/ instead - I'm sorry for being pedantic, but it's good to know the difference between JSON and JS objects/arrays

Comment: I get it now. I fixed my example. Thank you for showing me a way.

Comment: @evolutionxbox no problem, you're trying to help. you should feel good because I learned something.

Comment: @evolutionxbox can you help me :(

Comment: So you want to loop through all the properties of an object (and its "children") and remove it if it is not `true` in the other object?

Comment: You provide only `true` values, Is there any `false` also?

Comment: @Nur no. only changed keys come true

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes. I want to delete the ones that are not true by referring to my validation object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate by keys (compare) and add input values...

```js
const input = { "name": "Example name", "company": { "name": "new company", "size": "FIVE", "licenseInfo": { "isActive": "0" } } }
const compare = { "name": true, "company": { "size": true, "licenseInfo": { "isActive": true } } }

function filter(input, compare) {
    const output = {};
    for (const key in compare)
        output[key] = typeof compare[key] == "object"
            ? filter(input[key], compare[key])
            : input[key];

    return output;
}
console.log(filter(input, compare));
```